# next-stripe error Module not found: Can't resolve './dist/client'

Tags: node.js, next.js, stripe-payments

I have a Nextjs app and I imported the module next-stripe (npm i next-stripe) to use the createCheckoutSession. When I run my code I get the following error:
`./node_modules/next-stripe/client.js remote: Module not found: Can't resolve './dist/client'`

When I look into the node_modules/next-stripe/client.js file it shows:
`module.exports = require('./dist/client').default`

However, there is no `dist` folder in the `node_modules/next-stripe` folder but the folder in it is called `src`. When I change the code in the client.js file to `module.exports = require('./src/client').default` in my local environment it seems to work, but I can't do that remotely on my heroku cloud server.

Not sure if I am doing anything wrong or how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use this package?

You can directly use Stripe's package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe which is very well documented here: https://stripe.com/docs/api